# Django - retrieve the form input values

Tags: django, create-view

I'm working in a Create view and I'm trying to overwrite the `form_valid` method. My goal is to create a record in another table before creating in the current model.

For instance, my form has a field called name. My question is how can I retrieve this fields value within the `form_valid` method. A piece of code to help you understand my question:

```
class DeliveryCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Delivery
    form_class = DeliveryForm 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(DeliveryCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

        name = form["Name"] # I know this is wrong. That's the part I don't know how to do.        

        self.object.permissions.add(self.request.user)
        self.object.save()
        return response
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I just realized I can use the current object, like this:

```
self.object.name
```

This gives me the name, this object if filled with all the information.